# How do I get the DST amount from MomentJS

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Is there a way to get the amount of time for a DST transition.  For example there are some odd Timezones out there that have a 30 minute transition.  Another way for me to get this is to get the utc offsets for standard and dst time and I can subtract the two.

If I do moment.tz('America/Chicago')._z.offsets I can access a large array of all the offsets.  However I need to know which index into the array is for the current year.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you check if this helps ? http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-ambiguous-inputs/

Comment: You can create one date for 1 June and another for 1 December and compare the time zone offsets. There are many places that don't have daylight saving at all.

Comment: I'll post a more complete answer later, but Rob is mostly right.  Create two moments and check the `utcOffset` difference between them.  Keep in mind that transitions may have changed over the years, and not all transitions are due to DST.  Also, the only zone that *currently* transitions by 30 min for DST is `Australia/Lord_Howe`.  All the rest are 1 hr or not at all.  Oh, and then there's Antarctica.  ;)

Comment: Why June and December 1?  In the U.S. it would be March 13th and Nov 6 in 2016.   First I need to figure out what the DST dates are.  Since they change from year to year per country.  Any idea on how to figure which dates have DST changes?

Comment: FYI--I was able to narrow down the _z array by including the extra timezone-utils.js file and then 
moment.tz.filterYears(moment.tz('Australia/Adelaide')._z, 2016, 2016). This gets me down to an array of three elements.  Since the array starts with an _ I would if its safe for me to use as its probably meant to be private.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will return the current difference in UTC offsets between Jan 1 and Jun 1 of the current year - which is probably what you're looking for:

```
function getDSTBias(tz) {
    var janOffset = moment.tz({month: 0, day: 1}, tz).utcOffset();
    var junOffset = moment.tz({month: 5, day: 1}, tz).utcOffset();
    return Math.abs(junOffset - janOffset);
}
```

These are relatively safe dates to test, as they are in the middle of winter and in the middle of summer - though which is which depends on northern or southern hemisphere.  No DST transitions will occur [anywhere in the world](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/2016a.html) on these two dates.

You may see other code recommending July 1st, but [DST weirdness in Morocco](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/morocco) can make Jul 1 a standard-time date.

If you don't like the idea of hard-coding dates, here's an alternate approach:

```
function getOffsetDelta(tz) {
    var z = moment.tz.zone(tz);
    var i = z._index(moment());
    return i < z.offsets.length-1 ? Math.abs(z.offsets[i] - z.offsets[i+1]) : 0;
}
```

This approach gives the difference in offsets between *now* and whatever the next scheduled transition is. Note that there are other reasons for transitions than just DST - such as standard offset changes.

Also note that this alternate approach does not constrain the time to the current year.  So if DST is planned to be canceled in a future year, it will reflect in the result.  You could change this to test against the *last* transition, but this too will give strange results such as saying that `America/Phoenix` has 60 minute delta, because [Arizona experimented briefly with DST in 1967](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/phoenix?syear=1960).

So, in most cases, the first approach is probably best.